# Add Namespace Prefix To root node

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, prefix

I need to change the namespace of the root node and add the namespace prefix to only root element not for child elements.

I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Class xmlns="https://api.ladbrokes.com/v1/sportsbook-couchbase/SportsbookCouchbase.xsd">
<blurb >Test</blurb>
<channels >
<e >I</e>
<e >J</e>
<e >K</e>
</channels>
<classSortCode >Test</classSortCode>
<classStatus >Test</classStatus>
<creationDateTime >2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</creationDateTime>
<isActive >true</isActive>
<lastUpdatedDateTime >2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</lastUpdatedDateTime>
<locale >Test</locale>
</Class>
```

And I need this to become

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ns0:Class xmlns:ns0="https://api.ladbrokes.com/v1/sportsbook-couchbase/Temp.xsd">
<blurb >Test</blurb>
<channels >
<e >I</e>
<e >J</e>
<e >K</e>
</channels>
<classSortCode >Test</classSortCode>
<classStatus >Test</classStatus>
<creationDateTime >2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</creationDateTime>
<isActive >true</isActive>
<lastUpdatedDateTime >2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</lastUpdatedDateTime>
<locale >Test</locale>
</ns0:Class>
```

Can i achieve this using XSLT? Kindly assist me in this regard.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: In your example, the child elements have been changed from being in the `...SportsbookCouchbase.xsd` namespace to the `NULL` namespace. Was that intentional?

Comment: yes sir, that was intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can give the document element a different namespace and move all of the other elements into the null namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns0="https://api.ladbrokes.com/v1/sportsbook-couchbase/Temp.xsd">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<ns0:Class xmlns:ns0="https://api.ladbrokes.com/v1/sportsbook-couchbase/Temp.xsd">
  <blurb>Test</blurb>
  <channels>
    <e>I</e>
    <e>J</e>
    <e>K</e>
  </channels>
  <classSortCode>Test</classSortCode>
  <classStatus>Test</classStatus>
  <creationDateTime>2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</creationDateTime>
  <isActive>true</isActive>
  <lastUpdatedDateTime>2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</lastUpdatedDateTime>
  <locale>Test</locale>
</ns0:Class>
```

For clarification, this is how you can change the namespace for the document element and leave everything else in the namespace they already had.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ns0="https://api.ladbrokes.com/v1/sportsbook-couchbase/Temp.xsd">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the result from that. Note the small but critical difference in the namespace declarations at the top:

```
<ns0:Class xmlns:ns0="https://api.ladbrokes.com/v1/sportsbook-couchbase/Temp.xsd" 
     xmlns="https://api.ladbrokes.com/v1/sportsbook-couchbase/SportsbookCouchbase.xsd">
  <blurb>Test</blurb>
  <channels>
    <e>I</e>
    <e>J</e>
    <e>K</e>
  </channels>
  <classSortCode>Test</classSortCode>
  <classStatus>Test</classStatus>
  <creationDateTime>2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</creationDateTime>
  <isActive>true</isActive>
  <lastUpdatedDateTime>2013-03-21T22:29:01.58+05:30</lastUpdatedDateTime>
  <locale>Test</locale>
</ns0:Class>
```